# Access interface implemented method using interface object

Tags: php, interface

I was going through the dependency injection docs and i have seen something below, in this code they have created an inreface's object then called the implemented function. I am confused here, is this the option available in Dependency injection or is it a opps feature.

```
class StoreService {
private $geolocationService;

public function __construct(GeolocationService $geolocationService) 
{
    $this->geolocationService = $geolocationService;
}

public function getStoreCoordinates($store) {
    return $this->geolocationService->getCoordinatesFromAddress($store->getAddress());
}
```

}

```
interface GeolocationService {
    public function getCoordinatesFromAddress($address);
}


     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
class GoogleMaps implements GeolocationService 
{
    public function getCoordinatesFromAddress($address) {
        // calls Google Maps webservice
    }
}

class OpenStreetMap implements GeolocationService 
{
   public function getCoordinatesFromAddress($address) {
     // calls OpenStreetMap webservice
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to PHP-DI, this is all native PHP. This is how interfaces work in PHP.